# The "cap" of Golang

Tags: arrays, go, slice

The following go code:

```
var numbers4 = [...]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
slice := numbers4[4:6:8] 
fmt.Printf("%d\n", cap(slice))
```

Why is `cap(slice)` equal to `4`?

I used to thought that should be `2`.

Comment: [Does that answer ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500282/is-working-past-the-end-of-a-slice-idiomatic) Should it be considered a duplicate ?

Comment: Maybe not a duplicate, but the answer you link to is also very informative.  Thanks.  I agree with that responder that go programmers should know how slices are implemented.  Slices are a very powerful programming mechanism and come in useful in many different ways.

Answer (score 5):

`numbers4[4:6:8]` is a [full slice expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions):

> For an array, pointer to array, or slice `a` (but not a string), the primary expression
>
> ```
> a[low : high : max]
> ```
>
> constructs a slice of the same type, and with the same length and elements as the simple slice expression `a[low : high]`. Additionally, it **controls the resulting slice's capacity by setting it to `max - low`**.

The spec says the full slice expression controls the capacity, limiting it to `max - low`, which in your case is `8 - 4 = 4`.

The capacity is **not** the "extra" elements of which the slice may be extended, the capacity is the max length to which a slice may be extended, which includes current length + extra elements beyond the length.

```
slice := numbers4[4:6:8]

len(slice) = 6 - 4 = 2
cap(slice) = 8 - 4 = 4
```

Answer (score 3):

> The capacity is the number of elements in the underlying array
>   (beginning at the element referred to by the slice pointer).

from [Go Slices: usage and internals](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals).

Basically, it means cap != len.
So, the slice starts at #4, and finishes at #8, hence, cap is `8 - 4 = 4`.

Comment: Thanks, it helps me a lot