# golang slice, slicing a slice with slice[a:b:c]

Tags: go, slice

I read [go slice usage and internals](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals) and [Slice](http://blog.golang.org/slices) and [Effective go#slice](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#slices) but there is nothing about slicing a slice with 3 number like this : `slice[a:b:c]`

For example this code :

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var s = []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"}
    fmt.Println(s[1:2:6], len(s[1:2:6]), cap(s[1:2:6]))
    fmt.Println(s[1:2:5], len(s[1:2:5]), cap(s[1:2:5]))
    fmt.Println(s[1:2], len(s[1:2]), cap(s[1:2]))

}
```

[go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/up387gsFs8) result is this :

```
[b] 1 5
[b] 1 4
[b] 1 6
```

I can understand that the third one is something about capacity, but what is the exact meaning of this?
Do I miss something in documents?

Comment: I explained it at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18911267/6309

Comment: See http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions especially "Full slice expressions": The third index allows to limit the capacity of the subslice which is usefull if you want to append freely to the subslice without overwriting the original values (e.g. because the have been subsliced to an other slice).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The syntax has been introduced in Go 1.2, as I mentioned in "[Re-slicing slices in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18911267/6309)".
It is documented in [Full slice expressions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions):

```
a[low : high : max]
```

> constructs a slice of the same type, and with the same length and elements as the simple slice expression `a[low : high]`.
> Additionally, it controls the resulting slice's capacity by setting it to `max - low`.
> Only the first index may be omitted; it defaults to 0.
>
> After slicing the array `a`:
>
> ```
> a := [5]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
> t := a[1:3:5]
> ```
>
> the slice t has type []int, length 2, capacity 4, and elements
>
> ```
> t[0] == 2
> t[1] == 3
> ```

The [design document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GKKdiGYAghXRxC2BFrSEbHBZZgAGKQ-yXK-hRKBo0Kk/pub) for that feature had the following justification:

> It would occasionally be useful, for example in custom `[]byte` allocation managers, to be able to hand a slice to a caller and know that the caller cannot edit values beyond a given subrange of the true array.
>
> The addition of `append` to the language made this somewhat more important, because **`append` lets programmers overwrite entries between `len` and `cap` without realizing it or even mentioning `cap`**.

---

2022: [svitanok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16386335/svitanok) adds for Go 1.19+:

> while the capacity of a "derivative" slice doesn't exceed the one specified by the third index during its creation the slice is still "from" the same spot in the memory as its original ("true") slice, so the changes applied to it will affect the original slice.
>
> And if then, for example, you append to this derivative slice the amount of elements that would cause its capacity to be increased, this new slice will occupy a different place in the memory, and so the changes made to it will not affect the slice it originated from.

Comment: (Go 1.19) I'd just like to mention this for anyone wondering as I was: while the capacity of a "derivative" slice doesn't exceed the one specified by the third index during its creation the slice is still "from" the same spot in the memory as its original("true") slice, so the changes applied to it will affect the original slice. And if then, for example, you append to this derivative slice the amount of elements that would cause its capacity to be increased, this new slice will occupy a different place in the memory, and so the changes made to it will not affect the slice it originated from.

Comment: @svitanok Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. Feel free to edit if you need to amend it.

Answer (score 8):

In a slice expression `slice[a:b:c]` or `aSlice[1:3:5]`

```
a:b or 1:3 -> gives length
a:c or 1:5 -> gives capacity
```

We can extract both `length` and `capacity` from a slice expression with 3 numbers/indices, without looking at the source slice/array.

```
expression| aSlice[low:high:max]  or aSlice[a:b:c]    or aSlice[1:3:7]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Length    | len(aSlice[low:high]) or len(aSlice[a:b]) or len(aSlice[1:3])
Capacity  | len(aSlice[low:max])  or len(aSlice[a:c]) or len(aSlice[1:7])
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Read more here at [Slice Expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions)

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/f_OMDuLXYAh)

Answer (score -1):

Actually Go slice have a pointer and pointing to the array and it holds length and capacity of the array and we can show it like will be

pointer:length:capacity

and append is used for adding same new length.

```
    sl1 := make([]int, 6)
    fmt.Println(sl1)

    sl2 := append(sl1, 1)
    fmt.Println(sl2)
```

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
```